# How to get All Section Names from ini file

Tags: c#, ini

I want to get the list of sections from an ini file.I have only one section in my file now and my below code is returning null.

I tried various methods using GetSectionNamesListA and GetPrivateProfileSectionNames. None of them seem to help

```
   public string[] GetSectionNames(string path)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(buffer, buffer.Length, path);
        string allSections = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
        string[] sectionNames = allSections.Split('\0');
        return sectionNames;
    }
```

Using:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
  static extern int GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(byte[] pszReturnBuffer, int nSize, string lpFileName);
```

I am getting null returned inspite of a section being present.

Comment: People are still using ini files?!

Comment: Lol @DavidG - just what I thought.  But seriously, reading the ini file as a list using `File.ReadAllLines()` is by far the easiest way to get all the sections.  You just need to find all the group matches for a regular expression of `\[.*\]` (or simply  `text.StartsWith("[") && text.Trim().EndsWith("]")`)

Comment: I am with @Archer.. ini files are SO EASY to parse.  I wouldn't even use the Windows API.  In addition, the windows API will barf if there is more than one section with the same name which your code will not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use a library like [INI Parser](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser)

Here is an example using the library:

```
var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
IniData data = parser.ReadFile("file.ini");
foreach (var section in data.Sections)
{
   Console.WriteLine(section.SectionName);
}
```

And in your case `GetPrivateProfileSectionNames` doesn't give the section names because it expects the full path of the file. If you give it a relative path, it will try to find it in the Windows folder.

> The name of the initialization file. If this parameter is NULL, the function searches the Win.ini file. If this parameter does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the file in the Windows directory.

One way to fix that is to use `Path.GetFullPath(path)`:

```
path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
```

And this [page](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPrivateProfileSectionNames.html) shows the proper usage of `GetPrivateProfileSectionNames`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern uint GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(IntPtr pszReturnBuffer, uint nSize, string lpFileName);

public static string[] SectionNames(string path)
{
    path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
    uint MAX_BUFFER = 32767;
    IntPtr pReturnedString = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)MAX_BUFFER);
    uint bytesReturned = GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(pReturnedString, MAX_BUFFER, path);
    if (bytesReturned == 0)
        return null;
    string local = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pReturnedString, (int)bytesReturned).ToString();
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pReturnedString);
    //use of Substring below removes terminating null for split
    return local.Substring(0, local.Length - 1).Split('\0');
}
```

Comment: I am not able to download IniParser. Any other solution?

Comment: @Cherylaksh do you mean you can't use it, or can't download it? Because it has a nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the package downloaded and it works fine.! :)